# MVC TempData issue

Tags: model-view-controller

there;
       I have a very strange Tempdata issue in my MVC project. This is my pseudoCode;

```
  public class MyController: Controller
  {
    public ActionResult CreateInvoiceAndCustomerContact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateCustomerContact_Invoice()
    {
       {
          _MyFileCreationObj.CreateTtextFile();
       }
       TempData["ResultMessage"] = "hello";
       return RedirectToAction("CreateInvoiceAndCustomerContact");
    }
}

In object _MyFileCreationObj I have a method which uses "StreamWriter" to create text file:

   public void CreateInvoiceAndCustomerContact()
   {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportedFile))
        {
           //write text to a file
        }
   }
```

The problem I am having is: 
      The "TempData["ResultMessage"]" won't display in my view.

If I commented out StreamWriter block then there is NO problem showing "TempData["ResultMessage"]" in my view.

Can someone please please please help this?

Cheers
Rob.

Comment: I also tried another test with code:     public ActionResult TestTempData()
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\folder\sth.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("sth!!!");
            }

            TempData["Message"] = "TestMsg";
            return RedirectToAction("LoadInvoiceAndCustomerContact");
        } This message just can not be displayed on the view. If I remove the the "Using" block then no problem displaying the message. Can someone have an explanation to this please?   Chees, Robert

Answer (score 0):

After googling and asking question in ASP.NET forum, I finally fixed the issue:
I write my text file to the "BIN" folder which causes the restart of the application pool!!! See link: [Common reasons why your application pool may unexpectedly recycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx)
That why I lost my TempData. By changing the file location, everything works now.

Cheers
Rob